# Why is this a static context?

Tags: java, static

I am relatively new to java and don't understand why the setter method is a static context when I haven't used "static" anywhere.

```
public class Appointment {
    LocalDateTime Time;
    Doctor Doctor;
    Patient Patient;
    String Notes;

    public Appointment(LocalDateTime time, Doctor doc, Patient pat, String notes){
        Time = time;
        Doctor = doc;
        Patient = pat;
        Notes = notes;
    }


    public void setNotes(String Notes) {
        Appointment.Notes = Notes;
    }


}
```

EDIT: Someone commented the answer so I cant mark it as correct but I put Appointment.Notes instead of this.Notes

Comment: Why what is a static context? This is a class.

Comment: What makes you think this is a static context?

Comment: There is an error in your setter method because `Appointment` is a class, so `Appointment.Notes` is trying to access the instance variable `Notes` as if it were a static variable. Write `this.notes` instead.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't start variable names with capitals as it tends to confuse with class names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the syntax for assigning a static variable (not necessarily a member of the current class).

```
public class Appointment {

        Appointment.Notes = Notes;
```

Instead write:

```
        this.Notes = Notes;
```

Or better change the variable name to something standard:

```
        this.notes = notes;
```

I strongly suggest sticking to naming conventions. Also it is useful to quote the actual compiler error message in questions.